# English translation of Sefer Machaneh Ephrayim

Tags: jewish-books, translation, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Is there an English translation on the Internet or in print of the book of the chiddushei harav efraim navon?

---

As of *Tammuz* 5772, I have encountered no evidence that such translation exists.

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Comment: @DovF - So why don't you suggest *No* for an answer?

Comment: @AdamMosheh You can't prove a negative.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I can't say no. I am hypothesizing based on my knowledge and experience but I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: @ba yeah that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are capable of reading the Hebrew to some degree and your intention is to use the English translation as an aid to in-depth study, why not take on the task of translating it yourself? For myself, I am presently working to translate Sefer Chafetz Chaim, even though there are superb translations and adaptations available in print.

Comment: As far as I know, there's only one translation into English of the entirety of _Chafetz Chayim_ (published by Mazal Elul, who is working through all the books of _R' Yisrael Meir_).